# Handlebarsjs: render multiple passes with nested templates

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I see many things that just refers me to partials which sucks because they have to built out of the layout context.

What I'm wanting to do is make nested templates

For example:

```
<div id="person">
  {{name}}
  <div id="address">
    {{street}}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var outer = Handlebars.compile($('#person').html());
  outer({ name: 'someone special' });

  var inner = Handlebars.compile($('#address').html());
  inner({ street: 'somewhere cool' });
</script>
```

When running this, the inner template is never rendered as the outer templating gobbles it up.

It would be nice if you could namespace nested templates like this:

```
{{> name}}
<div id="person">
  {{name}}
  {{> address}}
  <div id="address">
    {{street}}
  </div>
  {{/> address}}
</div>
{{/> name}}

<script>
  var outer = Handlebars.compile($('#person').html(), 'name');
  outer({ name: 'someone special' });

  var inner = Handlebars.compile($('#address').html(), 'address');
  inner({ street: 'somewhere cool' });
</script>
```

or something like this, so that when the outer renders, it will leave the address alone and let inner render address itself without removing it from the DOM.

Is anything like this possible?

The reason for this question is that I'm using backbone and want to separate out all of my small views but it compiles to one file. when the outer is templated with handlebars, everything else breaks. I don't want to use partials as that just take everything out of the flow of the html document for the designers.

#### EDIT

I think what I really need is a way to do `{{noparse}}` and from the registerHelper just return the raw html between the noparse tags

Comment: I don't get the question.. Why can't you do this?
`var templ = Handlebars.compile($('#person').html());
  templ({ name: 'someone special', street: 'somewhere cool'});`

Comment: because at the time name is rendered, street does not exist. Street is rendered from the address controller/model/view which. but the person template just gobbles up the html or any reference to it I can't render the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Here is a demo of a `no-parse` helper](http://jsbin.com/kiqija/1/edit)**. To use this functionality, you will need to use a version of at least v2.0.0-alpha.1. You can get it from the handlebars [build page](http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-listing.html?sort=lastmod&sortdir=desc). [Here is the pull request that details about it](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/730).

Here is the relevant code.

Template

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div id="person">
  {{name}}
    {{{{no-parse}}}}
      <div id="address">
        {{street}}
      </div>
    {{{{/no-parse}}}}
  </div>
</script>

Handlebars.registerHelper('no-parse', function(options) {
  return options.fn();
});
```

Comment: That certainly works. One of these days I'll have to speak at a summit of how we convolute stuff in an attempt to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a crucial step.  You have to take the template & compile it (which you're doing) but you also have to register the partial.

Really the pattern you want to use is the partial template - where you register the inner template as a partial template then fill it with the person's address data - there is a [great example here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers), but this also will help in your specific HTML setup.

```
<script id="person-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 {{#each person}}
   {{name}}
   {{> address}}
 {{/each}}
</script>   

<script id="address-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <div class="address">
        <h2>{{street}}</h2>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#person-template").html());
    Handlebars.registerPartial("address", $("#address-partial").html());

    template({ name: 'someone special', street: 'somewhere cool' });
  }
</script>
```